# Is My jQuery Code Firing? Tracking Google Analytics Custom Events in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-analytics, universal-analytics, event-tracking

I want to track a click for "Get in Touch" icon column in Universal Analytics via jQuery.

I've created a custom.js file to put my Google Analytics event tracking code that fires in every page:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        $('#mpcth_icon_column_jiJQk a').on('click', function() {
          ga('send', 'event', 'Internal Link', 'click', 'flashforge-usa.com/support/get-in-touch');
    });
        $('#mpcth_icon_column_jiJQk').on('click', function() {
          ga('send', 'event', 'Internal Link', 'click', 'flashforge-usa.com/support/get-in-touch');
    });
        $('#mpcth_icon_column_jiJQk .mpc-vc-icon-column-wrap').on('click', function() {
          ga('send', 'event', 'Internal Link', 'click', 'flashforge-usa.com/support/get-in-touch');
    });
        $('#mpcth_icon_column_jiJQk .mpc-vc-icon-column-wrap a').on('click', function() {
          ga('send', 'event', 'Internal Link', 'click', 'flashforge-usa.com/support/get-in-touch');
      });

    });
```

In my theme's header.php, I've added the below code to link my custom.js:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo MPC_THEME_URI ?>/js/custom.js"></script>
```

In Google Analytics, I've set category: Internal Link, action: click, label: flashforge-usa.com/support/get-in-touch.

However, in Real-Time, I don't see the event being tracked.

How do I know if my jQuery is firing at all? I'm not getting any errors in Chrome's console...

Comment: Have you tried adding console.log debug messages? Instead of firing the event, print some debug stuff. That would be my starting point in debugging.

Comment: Or use your network tab or the Chrome GA debugger extension to see if any data is sent to the Google Analytics endpoint.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've very limited knowledge in this field but I installed Chrome GA debugger and also went into the network tab. I see custom.js (which has my jQuery code for firing UA event tracking) with status 200/OK, so I assume it's firing correctly? If so, what could be other reasons the event's not being tracked?

Comment: Any updates to this, OP?